# MVC - NSFetchRequest in model file without UIKit

Tags: ios, swift

In my ViewController, I have a function for fetching all the 'headingNumbers' (an attribute of the entity 'Vocabulary'). I understood that this is not good MVC practice.

So I created a new swift file. 
I did not import UIKit. Youtube Stanford - Developing iOS 9 Apps with Swift - 2, 22:53: "Never import UI KIT in a model file because the model is UI independent"
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j50mPzDMWVQ)

However, now I get these messages like
"Use of unresolved identifier 'UIApplication'".
Which makes sense, as I did not import the UIKit.
The question is: how do I now execute a fetch request in my new swift file.
(As you probably now by now, I am a beginner)

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class QueryData {

private var selectedHeadingNumber:String = "-123456789"
private var setOfHeadingNumbers:[String] = [String]()

func getHeadingNumbers2() -> [String] {


    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

        // Create Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Vocabulary")

        // Add Sort Descriptor
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "headingNumber", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Execute Fetch Request
        do {
            let result = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

            for managedObject in result {
                if let foundHeadingNumber = managedObject.valueForKey("headingNumber") {

                    if let result_number = foundHeadingNumber as? NSNumber
                    {
                        let result_string = "\(result_number)"

                        if !setOfHeadingNumbers.contains(result_string) {
                            print("Headingnumber: \(foundHeadingNumber) ")
                            setOfHeadingNumbers.append(result_string)

                            print("updated selectedHeadingNumber: ", selectedHeadingNumber)
                            selectedHeadingNumber = result_string

                            // set the default lessonnumber to the first lesson
                            if selectedHeadingNumber == "-123456789" {
                                selectedHeadingNumber = result_string
                                print("updated selectedHeadingNumber: ", selectedHeadingNumber)
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    //setOfHeadingNumbers.append(first)
                }
            }

        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print(fetchError)
        }

    } // end of if statement

    return setOfHeadingNumbers

} // end of func

} // end of class
```

Comment: You need to import what you use. I'd say that the code you showed wouldn't qualify as a "model class". It has UI (or system) dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is `NSManagedObjectContex`. Pass it as an argument to method:

```
func getHeadingNumbers2(inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [String]
{
    ...
}
```

Or inject it as dependency in initializer

```
class QueryData
{
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext)
    {
        self.context = context
    }

    func getHeadingNumbers2() -> [String]
    {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Vocabulary")
        let result = try self.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'inject it as dependency' appears to be ok (no more exclamation marks). Thanks. Now I have an issue getting the return value in ViewController. Will first read more documentation.